# Some basic questions about OpenAL buffers

Tags: openal

I just started working with OpenAL and everything seems fine so far, i've tried some tutorials, managed to load and play some sounds, but before i start implementing something more complex, i'd like to make sure i understand how OpenAL works.

Basically my goal is to make a simple system, where i can give commands such as "play this and this, stop playing that" without having to care about anything. Let's assume that the program has to work with 150 sounds, which are 250 MB in total when decompressed to PCM and all of it is available at the beginning.

In OpenAL, there are sources and buffers. I understand that i'm supposed to have a pool of sources and reuse them. What i don't understand and haven't been able to find anywhere, is what the buffers actually represent. Are they a limited resource or just regular storage, perhaps converted to a format that can be played easily, but still in regular memory?

**In the situation i described, should i:**

- A) create 150 buffers in the beginning and fill them all with 250 MB of data, some of which might be an hour long sounds, keep it for the whole duration of the program and play them when needed, or
- B) load the 250 MB into memory and load each sound into a buffer right before playback, in small chunks, and release them right after?

If A, what is the purpose of streaming data into small buffers and then queueing them?

If B, how many buffers and how much data in them is safe? Should i also make a buffer pool and reuse them?

Also, i have an additional question about buffer queueing. I understand that i can either set a source's buffer (as a property) or queue it (doing both would be an error right?). I was surprised though, that apparently i also have to unqueue them. Why doesn't this happen automatically as soon as the buffer is played? And do i have to unqueue them in the same order they were queued?

Thank you for helping me understand this.